# Regular expression: matching only if not ending in particular sequence

Tags: regex

I would like to test a url that does NOT end in **.html**

This is the pattern I come up with:

```
[/\w\.-]+[^\.html$]
```

The following matches because it does not end in **.html**

```
/blog/category/subcategory/
```

This doesn't match because it ends in **.html**:

```
/blog/category/subcategory/index.html
```

However, the following does not match, although I want it to match, because it ends in **.ht** and not **.html**

```
/blog/category/subcategory/index.ht
```

How should I change my pattern?

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind assertion if your regular expression engine supports it:

```
^[/\w\.-]+(?<!\.html)$
```

If you don't have lookbehind assertions but you do have lookaheads then you can use that instead:

```
^(?!.*\.html$)[/\w\.-]+$
```

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/7pFKeWlfy8)

Comment: @Khnle: I'd expect that it depends on the engine and on the distribution of your input strings.

Answer (score 18):

What engine are you using? If it's one that supports lookahead assertions, you can do the following:

```
/((?!\.html$)[/\w.-])+/
```

If we break it out into the components, it looks like this:

```
(            # start a group for the purposes of repeating
 (?!\.html$) # negative lookahead assertion for the pattern /\.html$/
 [/\w.-]     # your own pattern for matching a URL character
)+           # repeat the group
```

This means that, for every character, it tests that the pattern /.html$/ can't match here, before it consumes the character.

You may also want to anchor the entire pattern with `^` at the start and `$` at the end to force it to match the entire URL - otherwise it's free to only match a portion of the URL. With this change, it becomes

```
/^((?!\.html$)[/\w.-])+$/
```