# NLTK regexp for noun phrases to not match ending with a preposition

Tags: regex, parsing, grammar, nltk, regex-negation

I'm trying to identify noun phrases using NLTK, but am still a little green on regular expressions.

I was originally using a regexp like this:

```
  NP: {<PP\$>?<JJ.*>*<NN.*>+}
```

But I find that I keep getting expressions ending with prepositions, so things like:
"Demonstration projects for", ending in the preposition "for", are matching, which is undesirable.  (I don't see how yet, even with the syntax above---as far as I can tell, this should always end in at least one noun, right?)

So, I reduced the quantifier to a lazy one by changing it to:

```
  NP: {<PP\$>?<JJ.*>*<NN.*>+?}
```

But now I get matches like "Orleans" instead of "New Orleans."  It seems like it isn't matching phrases at all, anymore.

Finally, I tried using a look-ahead (that I learned about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973977/regular-expression-matching-only-if-not-ending-in-particular-sequence)) to explicitly remove the terminal preposition:

```
  NP: {((?!<IN>$)(<PP\$>?<JJ.*>*<NN.*>+))+}
```

This had no effect at all---I'm still getting things like "Demonstration projects for" as matches.  How can I keep my noun phrases free from terminal prepositions?

If there's an easier, more optimized way to get noun phrases, that would also be appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using your original grammar `(S (NP Demonstration/NN projects/NNS) for/IN the/DT (NP science/NN fair/NN) ./.)`. I'm thinking the POS tags for "for" are incorrectly labeled as `NN`.

Comment: Hmm, that would make sense.  I'll investigate.