# How to exclude a URL when registering filters in ServletModule.configureServlets?

Tags: java, guice, sitebricks

I use [sitebricks](https://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks) to build a RESTful API on Google App Engine. I register two filters for all /rest/* URLs in my [GuiceCreator](https://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/wiki/GettingStarted). **How can I use the `filter("/rest/*)` syntax but exclude one specific URL?** I want that everything under /rest/* gets filtered except for /rest/1/foo.

I could enumerate all URLs that actually need to be filtered. But the obvious disadvantage of this is that it will be hard to maintain if I decide to add or remove endpoints.

```
new ServletModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        filter("/rest/*").through(ObjectifyFilter.class);
        filter("/rest/*").through(SomeOtherFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I am looking for a construct like

```
filter("/rest/*").exclude("/rest/1/foo").through(ObjectifyFilter.class).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to dhanji](https://raw.github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/3a2935d7057ed296d105fc750b8bc67b2856d13c/sitebricks/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/SitebricksServletModule.java), I fixed this by using `filterRegex()` instead of `filter()`. In my regular expression I am using a [negative lookbehind assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973977/regular-expression-matching-only-if-not-ending-in-particular-sequence). This filters all `/rest/.*` URLs except the ones ending with `/[0-9]/foo`.

```
new ServletModule() {
  @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {
    filter("^/rest/.*(?<!/\\d/foo)$").through(ObjectifyFilter.class);
    filter("^/rest/.*(?<!/\\d/foo)$").through(SomeOtherFilter.class);
  }
}
```